# Routing with POST ends up with 404

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to send a post to `/register/save`.

```
/**
 * @Route("/register/save/{data}", methods={"POST", "HEAD"})
 * @param $data
 */
public function save($data) {
    var_dump($data);
}
```

If I call the URL `localhost/register/save` (without any data) on my browser, I get the message

> No route found for "GET /register/save"

If call the URL with Postman with JSON as body, I get the message

> No route found for "POST /register/save" (404 Not Found)

Without `${data}` the route would work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `POST` methods, the parameters are passed in the request body, not as a url argument so the route doesn't even match since the parameter is missing.

```
/**
 * @Route("/register/save/", methods={"POST", "HEAD"})
 */
public function save(Request $request) {
    if ("POST" === $request->getMethod()) {
        var_dump($request->request->get('data'));
    }
}
```

See some examples of the [`Request` object](https://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html#symfony-request-object).

Comment: Thank you. That makes definitely sense! But in my case var_dump returns `NULL`. In Postman my JSON looks like this: `{
 "country": "USA",
 "language": "English"
}` ... I also changed `country` to `data` but even that returns `NULL`.

Comment: I solved it like this: `$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
var_dump($data['country']);`

Comment: Also you can use `if ($request->isMethod('POST') )`

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

1) Post data can not be set as query parameter, so it should not be part of the route url.

2) Data can be received using inbuilt symfony package **request**.

So here is the modified code:

```
/**
 * @Route("/register/save", methods={"POST", "HEAD"})
 *
 */
public function postSave(Request $request)
{
    var_dump($request->request->all());
}
```

Note: There should not be back slash at end of the route url.

Comment: Thank you but the var_dump returns an empty array. I am sending the post (JSON) with Postman.